# Charcters in Lubuntu are Stylized/Italic

Tags: lubuntu, fonts

I have ran across an issue with my fresh install of Lubuntu.  The font shows up ok, but the numerals do not.  Instead of a normal number, it shows "FontExample *11*" rather than "FontExample 11".

Any ideas?

I have tried gnome-tweaks to no avail.

TIA[Illustration of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaUNw.png)

Comment: Which release of Lubuntu?   (*Yes I should possibly be able to guess from picture; it is likely a LXQt, but it's better if we don't guess*)   Also if LXQt why would `gnome-tweaks` do anything?  or are you using LXDE & legacy Lubuntu?  (even then why? LXDE is GTK2 and not GTK3)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry.  My bad.  Here is the release : Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.  I am new to linux and a friend suggested gnome-tweaks.  I now know it isn't for LTS.

Comment: No `gnome-tweaks` is geared for adjusting GNOME Shell settings, the problem is GNOME Shell is GTK3, where as LXDE as used by Lubuntu 18.04 is GTK2 and thus uses GTK2 settings. `gnome-tweaks` may have some GTK2 settings, but it's geared for the GTK3 desktop it runs on (it happens to also work on other GTK3 desktops, alas LXDE isn't).  Lubuntu moved from depreciated GTK2 to LXQt (as used by KDE, even android & windows apps) instead.   Can you also provide the name of the "Theme" from the first tab; *I couldn't re-create your issue*.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2dy4Btk

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
I changed the font selection in "Customize Look and Feel:, "Widget", "Default Font".

Thanks for the help.